# Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, foreach, warnings

I have the follow array structure and I am successfully looping through the [LoyaltyHistory] part using a for each loop:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [LoyaltyHistory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [user_id] => 32
                    [points] => 4
                    [date] => 2012-02-07
                    [total] => 146
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [LoyaltyHistory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [user_id] => 32
                    [points] => -6
                    [date] => 2012-02-07
                    [total] => 140
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [LoyaltyHistory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [user_id] => 32
                    [points] => -5
                    [date] => 2012-02-07
                    [total] => 135
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [LoyaltyHistory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [user_id] => 32
                    [points] => 15
                    [date] => 2012-02-07
                    [total] => 150
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [LoyaltyHistory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [user_id] => 32
                    [points] => 5
                    [date] => 2012-02-10
                    [total] => 155
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [LoyaltyHistory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [user_id] => 32
                    [points] => 155
                    [date] => 2012-03-04
                    [total] => 305
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [LoyaltyHistory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [user_id] => 32
                    [points] => -5
                    [date] => 2012-03-04
                    [total] => 300
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [LoyaltyHistory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                    [user_id] => 32
                    [points] => 5
                    [date] => 2012-03-05
                    [total] => 305
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

the for each loop is structured as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($history as $hist) 
    {
       if($hist['LoyaltyHistory']['points'] > 0) $hist['LoyaltyHistory']['points'] = '+'.$hist['LoyaltyHistory']['points'];?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $hist['LoyaltyHistory']['date']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $hist['LoyaltyHistory']['points']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $hist['LoyaltyHistory']['total']; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                    <?php   } ?>
```

The for each loop is outputing the correct elements from the array but it is causing the following warning: `'Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'` and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Could it be because you're using `$history` as your looping variable but call `$h` inside of the loop?

Comment: Well spotted, forgot to update that reference from $h to $hist, will make an amendment to original post. Unfortunately that is not what is causing the issue.

Comment: I tried you example with your data and it works correctly. Try to define after which cycle you get this warning

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs mainly when the argument received by `foreach` is not an array.
Try adding `var_dump($history)` just before. One of your record must have a null value instead of an empty array.

Comment: var_dump gives the same as the output of the print_r in the initial post. As you can see all 'LoyaltyHistory' elements have a value.

Comment: But your foreach is not looping through `LoyaltyHistory` array, but instead through your main array. Can you show us more code?

Comment: I know what you mean but the listing in the initial post is showing the entire array structure and each array element has data. I'm not sure what other code would help. The only other code which is related is in the Controller:

$conditions = array("user_id" => $id);
  
$this->set('history', $this->LoyaltyHistory->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions)));

That is populating the $history array and passing the value to the VIEW.

Comment: Well, this could be a stupid question, but are you sure this warning is thrown by this foreach?

Comment: I didn't need the associated user array so I removed it from the 'LoyaltyHistory' array using $this->LoyaltyHistory->recursive = -1;
Now for each functioning okay, thanks for the advice, problem solved